# Sortable column headers based off dynamic input?

Tags: php, html

Firstly I'd like to apologize for the topic question... I simply couldn't think of a question. Mainly because I don't know what I am looking for. I just need a hint or a pointer to the general direction of how to solve my problem. I think this is where my inexperience with the web shows a little... Anyway!

So what I have right now is a drop down with users in it. Select the user, and info comes up in 4 columns. That info needs to be sortable from the column headers. I can do both things independently from each other (the selection and the sorting), but I think the post/submit of the dropdown happens before I can save the variables to be passed in the URL, so I can't get it to behave properly.

So here's the code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
  User: <select name="user_id">
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>" <?php echo ($user_id == $user['id'] ? 'selected' : ''); ?>><?php echo $user['name']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Select">
</form>

<table id="one-column-emphasis" summary="All Accounts">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width:20%"><a href="index.php?module=task_queue_list_per_user&action=view_list&sort=name">Name</a></th>
<th style="width:10%"><a href="index.php?module=task_queue_list_per_user&action=view_list&sort=priority">Priority</a></th>
<th style="width:10%"><a href="index.php?module=task_queue_list_per_user&action=view_list&sort=created_date">Date Created</a></th>
<th style="width:10%"><a href="index.php?module=task_queue_list_per_user&action=view_list&sort=created_date">Age</a></th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

What I think is happening is that the submit happens before the variables can be set to send to the database file. If I have a user selected and click on the column header to sort it, it takes me back to the default where there is no user selected.

Any ideas, tips or help?
Thanks

Comment: It sounds to me like when you click on one of the header links, it loads the page but no longer knows which user was selected. If you could put the user in the URL of the link as a variable, I bet you could make it work.

Comment: I'm trying that right now... hopefully it'll work.

Comment: so I can hold on to the user_id from the url now, but I'm not sure as to how to make the php that populates the columns, run again.